# typecasting on left hand side in C

Tags: c

I have a sample program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long long a;
    unsigned short b;
    b = 10;
    *(unsigned short *)&a = b;
    printf("a = %lld\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

I have one doubt regarding this line `*(unsigned short *)&a = b;`, generally we do typecasting on the right hand side, here I see typecasting on the left hand side.

I see what it was achieving with the above statement is that, the `short int` is stored in the LSB bits of `unsigned long long`, and the value in rest of the bits in `unsigned long long` variable might remain same. So for cases like this we do typecast on left hand side?

Any insights on this can you please share.

Comment: Strictly speaking this is *undefined behavior*. A correct way would be to rewrite the line as `memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof b);`

Comment: It doesn't matter what side it's on. The same thing could be done by casting on the right hand side: `unsigned short *p = (unsigned short *)&a;  *p = b;`

Comment: This is called [Type-Punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning).  But if what you want to do is put it in the lower bits, why not do: `a = a & (size appropriate mask) | b` ?

Comment: Agree on all the above mentioned approaches, it was some legacy codebase which im looking at and i see first time a typecast on left hand side, so curious to find out what could be reason to typecast on left hand side.

Comment: Because the programmer wanted to fake the type of the target of an assignment, the variable on the left side.  `*(blah *)&` is the (usually no-longer acceptable) idiom to treat a memory location as a different type (blah) than it actually is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code has undefined behavior for multiple reasons:

- modifying the initial 2 bytes of `a` via `*(unsigned short *)&a = b;` actually has undefined behavior: you are modifying the value of `a` via a pointer to a different type that is not a character type, the compiler could assume that the value of `a` has not been set because no assignment via type `unsigned long long` was performed since the definition of `a`
- `a` is uninitialized, so even if the first 2 bytes were modified, the remaining 6 byte are uninitialized, so passing the value to `printf` has undefined behavior.
- you are passing a value of type `unsigned long long` to `printf` where it expects a value of type `long long`.  Use `%llu` for unsigned conversion.
  Here is a modified version with defined behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long a = 0;
    unsigned short b = 10;
    memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof(b));
    printf("a = %llu\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that the output is implementation defined: depending on the size and representation of `unsigned short` and `unsigned long long`, modifying part of `a` with the bytes of `b` can produce a different value, potentially a trap value, albeit unlikely.

On current little endian systems, the output should be `a = 10`, and on big endian systems: `a = 42949672960`.